# How to connect XML and XSD and give errors if XML not valid?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate XML file using xsd file. I linked XML and XSD using

```
schemaLocation
```

**But XML not read XSD file.**

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="one.xsd">
    <person>
        <full_name>Hege Refsnes</full_name>
        <child_name>Cecilie</child_name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <full_name>Tove Refsnes</full_name>
        <child_name>Hege</child_name>
        <child_name>Stale</child_name>
        <child_name>Jim</child_name>
        <child_name>Borge</child_name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <full_name>Stale Refsnes</full_name>
    </person>
</persons>
```

**XSD file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="persons">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string"
                                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**If XML detect this XSD file it should be return an error**, (because I used "name" instead of "full_name" also I restrict "child_name" min - 1 and max - 2)

Can someone please explain how to link XML and XSD?

Comment: What are you using to read the XML document, can you provide the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the difference between `xsi:schemaLocation` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`:

- Use **`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`** when your XML ***is not*** in
  a *namespace*.
- Use **`xsi:schemaLocation`** when your XML ***is*** in a *namespace*.

### Not in a namespace

Your XML is not in a namespace, so you should use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`:

```
<persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="one.xsd">
```

### In a namespace

If your XML were in a namespace, then you'd use `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
<persons xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/person one.xsd"
         xmlns="http://example.com/person">
```

<sup>(Note the space between the namespace and the XSD filename; additional namespace URI and XSD filename pairs are allowed.)</sup>

And your XSD would use `targetNamespace`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/person" >
```

Comment: I have modified XML and XSD as you said, but it doesn't work. What I did, I tried to run this in XAMPP server. 
eg: http://localhost:8888/myfiles/test.xml

Then It returns "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 52: xmlns: 'http://example.com/person one.xsd' is not a valid URI
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error" error..

Comment: I fixed a mistake in the **In a namespace** example, but you shouldn't be using that example anyway.  Use the **Not in a namespace** example, because your XML is not using namespaces:  add `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="one.xsd"` to your `person` root element instead of `xsi:schemaLocation="one.xsd"`.